# Querying unmapped types with raw SQL queries in Entity Framework Core 7 or lower

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Is querying unmapped types with raw SQL queries available only in Entity Framework Core 8? I remember working on an ASP.NET Web API project using Entity Framework 6 where I was able to query unmapped types without any additional configuration.

When I try to execute the query below, I get an exception

> The element type 'server.Data.BikeStore.Order' used in 'SqlQuery' method is not natively supported by your database provider. Either use a supported element type, or use ModelConfigurationBuilder.DefaultTypeMapping to define a mapping for your type.

```
List<Order> order = await _BSDB.Database
                               .SqlQuery<Order>(FormattableStringFactory.Create("select * from BikeStore.sales.orders"))
                               .ToListAsync();
```

My configuration for the `Order` entity is as follows:

```
public partial class BikeStoreContext : DbContext 
{
    public BikeStoreContext() {}

    public BikeStoreContext(DbContextOptions<BikeStoreContext> options) : base(options) {}

    public virtual DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Name=ConnectionStrings:BSConnection");

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.OrderId)
                      .HasName("PK__orders__465962291A616684");

                entity.ToTable("orders", "sales");
 
                entity.Property(e => e.OrderId)
                      .HasColumnName("order_id");
                entity.Property(e => e.CustomerId)
                      .HasColumnName("customer_id");
                entity.Property(e => e.OrderDate)
                      .HasColumnType("date")
                      .HasColumnName("order_date");
                entity.Property(e => e.OrderStatus)
                      .HasColumnName("order_status");
                entity.Property(e => e.RequiredDate)
                      .HasColumnType("date")
                      .HasColumnName("required_date");
                entity.Property(e => e.ShippedDate)
                      .HasColumnType("date")
                      .HasColumnName("shipped_date");
                entity.Property(e => e.StaffId)
                      .HasColumnName("staff_id");
                entity.Property(e => e.StoreId)
                      .HasColumnName("store_id");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Customer)
                      .WithMany(p => p.Orders)
                      .HasForeignKey(d => d.CustomerId)
                      .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                      .HasConstraintName("FK__orders__customer__47DBAE45");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Staff)
                      .WithMany(p => p.Orders)
                      .HasForeignKey(d => d.StaffId)
                      .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                      .HasConstraintName("FK__orders__staff_id__49C3F6B7");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Store)
                      .WithMany(p => p.Orders)
                      .HasForeignKey(d => d.StoreId)
                      .HasConstraintName("FK__orders__store_id__48CFD27E");
            });
        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use https://www.nuget.org/packages/ErikEJ.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.SqlQuery/7.0.0-preview1

Comment: The table field names are the snake-case equivalent of the property names. Instead of explicit configuration you could [add a new convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/bulk-configuration#conventions) that maps property name to their snake_case equivalents using eg [Humanizer's `Underscore()`](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer/tree/5dfb5ae8b8f90d3f769a7ce389eb5f756305f746#underscore)

Comment: "Is querying unmapped types with raw SQL queries available only in Entity Framework Core 8?" Correct unless it's a simple scalar type  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew#raw-sql-queries-for-unmapped-types

Comment: @Charlieface It's strange because there are multiple tutorials online that show querying an unmapped type is supported even in EF Core 6.

https://youtu.be/BxMXBJYLdGI?si=KzU5wB77Ep3emm4o

Comment: That's EF6 not EF Core 6, different product. Yeah it's been an ongoing issue: when Core came out, lots of features were missing.